# Indirect speech, past tense use

Tags: verbs, past-tense, speech, syntactic-analysis

A member's post on another site has the structure:
*This a post I put on* [site] *and* [member] *suggested I **posted*** *here too.*
 (emphasis mine)

It appears that being reported speech, *post* is required to be in the past tense. 
However, the verb does not relate to action by the person being reported, rather the one reporting himself here. (Do we still need to use past tense?)

I find the sentence not as clear as it would have been with a simple present (wrong, perhaps):

*This a post I put on* [site] *and* [member] *suggested* (that) *I **post*** (it) *here too.*

Which would be preferable? Is the original grammatically correct and I am uncomfortable only because of being unfamiliar with the structure?

Is the above alternative allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are grammatical. If there’s any difference in meaning, I think it’s this. The past tense, *posted*, conforming as it does to the normal way of reporting speech, emphasises the reported nature of the suggestion. The use of *post*, on the other hand, emphasises the posting itself and can be read as performing a subjunctive function. This becomes clearer in the third person: *This is a post he put on [site] and [member] suggested (that) he post (it) here too.*